# Generic class with dynamic numbers of parameters

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to have a generic class with dynamic numbers of properties.

Example: (Class User)

```
User user1 = new User(1,"john","115 street","male",60,150, 15.125);
User user2 = new User(2,"john2","116 street","male",60,150, 15.125,"New york");
```

etc..

Can this be done in Java or could you recommend me any possible alternatives (if not)?

Comment: In strong languages such as Java, you can't dynamic create types because all types specified in compile-time. Your request solved in dynamic languages such as Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't support dynamic properties.

You can hack that with:

1. **Vararg methods**. Use the following signature `method(Object... objects)`.
   In that case you will have array of objects of your parameters passed to method - just process them as needed.
2. **Map structure**. I think its better solution, you have map with parameters inside your class. Where is key - name of your parameter and value its actual value.

   ```
   class User {    

   Map<String, Object> properties;

         Object getParameter(String key){
           return properties.get(key);
         }
         void addParameter(String key, Object value){
           properties.put(key, value);
         }

   }
   ```

Use method `addParameter` to add new parameter to your object.

Use method `getParameter` to extract value that needed (e.g `getParameter("name")`;)

Comment: You should not replace "normal", static properties (like name, address...) with a map. You loose type safety, editor support, spell check/compiler support (`getParameter("nam")` is valid), Java Beans support. Especially with the latter all tools that rely on this (like e.g. Hibernate) will fail or need extra work. Use a map only for truly dynamic parameters.

Comment: Sure. Even if attribute is optional you should not use Map (better to use Builder pattern)

Answer (score 8):

You can create a [varargs constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) in Java. In your case it would look like this:

```
public class User {
  private final long id;
  private final String name;
  private final Object[] parameters;

  public User(long id, String name, Object... parameters) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }
}
```

Although I think it's not a good pattern, and I would recommend you to come up with a better idea, for example a `Map<String, Object>` containing the optional parameters, or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but probably it is not a good idea.

You can do:

```
User(Object... args) {
    Object someObject = args[0]; // Check for length!
}
```

This is called `varargs` in Java lingo. But you get all your arguments as simple `Object`s within an `Object[]` and have to find a method to interpret them. The caller does not know what parameter to put at what position. If you want to allow this you typically won't use a language with Java's type and binding system.

The prime alternative -"the Java way of doing it"- is to overload the method; you can have more than one method with a given name and different arguments in a type. Example:

```
User(long id, String name) { ... }
User(long id, String name, String address) { ... }
// and so on
```

This can be cumbersome, so the IDEs have tools to generate these for you (at least for constructors).

Answer (score 2):

In your case(in my opinion) it will be better to use builder pattern. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Or see the Bloch's item 2 in Effective Java

Answer (score 1):

This is a candidate for the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)